# images on webpage getting stuck behind background (css)

Tags: cakephp

thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please check my answer. And next time make some research before asking here. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your css:

```
#profile {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;              <------- add this
    top: 150px;
    left: 850px;
    height: 216px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-position: -336px -238px;
}
```

Comment: I probably missed a `;`  ... copy and paste it again